# gcc not linking symbols from .o into application

Tags: g++, shared-libraries, undefined-symbol

I'm trying to link a c++ .o file into an application (also c++).  Here is the build line:

g++   -o ../objs/armv5sfLinux3.2gcc4.6.2.EV3/Touch_publisher ../objs/armv5sfLinux3.2gcc4.6.2.EV3/Touch_publisher.o ../objs/armv5sfLinux3.2gcc4.6.2.EV3/EV3_Touch.o ../objs/armv5sfLinux3.2gcc4.6.2.EV3/EV3_TouchPlugin.o ../objs/armv5sfLinux3.2gcc4.6.2.EV3/EV3_TouchSupport.o ../ev3/ev3dev.o -L/host-rootfs/home/rip/nfs/ev3dev/ndds.5.1.0/lib/armv5sfLinux3.2gcc4.6.2.EV3 -lnddscppz -lnddscz -lnddscorez -ldl -lnsl -lm -lpthread -lrt -lstdc++

The problematic .o is the ../ev3/ev3dev.o file.  After build, I get the Touch_publisher application, but nm reports:

```
root@arundel:~/rti_510/Touch# nm ../objs/armv5sfLinux3.2gcc4.6.2.EV3/Touch_publisher | grep ev3 | grep " U "
         U _ZN6ev3dev12touch_sensorC1ESs
         U _ZNK6ev3dev12touch_sensor7pressedEv
         U _ZNK6ev3dev6sensor9type_nameEv
```

If I do an nm on ev3dev.o, for the missing symbols, I get e.g.,

```
root@arundel:~/rti_510/Touch# nm ../ev3/ev3dev.o | grep _ZN6ev3dev12touch_sensorC1ESs
0000ee5c T _ZN6ev3dev12touch_sensorC1ESs
root@arundel:~/rti_510/Touch#
```

So a symbol is there.  What from the above is the detail I'm unware of?  The " T " means it is an external symbol...

Am I missing some esoteric flag on the command line?  The ev3dev.o file is built using:

```
BUILD:
        gcc -std=c++11 -shared -fpic -march=armv5t -mfloat-abi=soft -mlong-calls -o ev3dev.o ev3dev.cpp
```

Or maybe is there another step?  I've tried '-Wl,-whole-archive,../ev3/ev3dev.o,-no-whole-archive' but still get those pesky U symbols.

I have no -O# optimizations enabled.

I have read 20 or so similar questions ("missing symbols from linked object")

Thank you

addendum:  result of objdump rather than nm:

```
root@arundel:/host-rootfs/home/rip/nfs/ev3dev/rti_510/Touch# objdump -T Touch_publisher | grep \*UND\* | grep ev3dev   
00000000      DF *UND*  00000000              _ZNK6ev3dev12touch_sensor7pressedEv
00000000      DF *UND*  00000000              _ZNK6ev3dev6sensor9type_nameEv
00000000      DF *UND*  00000000              _ZN6ev3dev12touch_sensorC1ESs
root@arundel:/host-rootfs/home/rip/nfs/ev3dev/rti_510/Touch# objdump -t ../ev3/ev3dev.o | grep ev3dev | grep _ZNK6ev3dev12touch
0000f040 g     F .text  00000058              _ZNK6ev3dev12touch_sensor7pressedEv
root@arundel:/host-rootfs/home/rip/nfs/ev3dev/rti_510/Touch# objdump -t ../ev3/ev3dev.o | grep ev3dev | grep _ZNK6ev3dev6sensor9type
0000dd10 g     F .text  00000690              _ZNK6ev3dev6sensor9type_nameEv
root@arundel:/host-rootfs/home/rip/nfs/ev3dev/rti_510/Touch# objdump -t ../ev3/ev3dev.o | grep ev3dev | grep _ZN6ev3dev12touch      
0000ee5c g     F .text  000001e4              _ZN6ev3dev12touch_sensorC1ESs
0000ee5c g     F .text  000001e4              _ZN6ev3dev12touch_sensorC2ESs
root@arundel:/host-rootfs/home/rip/nfs/ev3dev/rti_510/Touch#
```

Comment: It probably is operating system specific. Why do you need to link an object file into an *existing* application? What you want to do is unclear. Do you want runtime [dynamic linking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading)? On Posix & Linux, use [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html). Maybe you need the `-rdynamic` flag at link time. Maybe you are missing some libraries!

Comment: I'm cross compiling on Ubuntu, under Qemu for Armv5sf.  I'm linking the ev3dev.o file with all the other .o files into the application all at once (not "into an /existing/ application").  I will try the -rdynamic... nop.  Still getting the unresolved externals.

Comment: And missing some libraries would be interesting, except the library with the symbols missing from the final application is there on the command line.

Comment: Check also with `file` and `objdump` each `*.o` file

Comment: Do those symbols appear only once or do they appear several times (with other letters than "U")?

Comment: @MarcGlisse -- only once, both nm and objdump -t only show single results.

Comment: @basile-starynkevitch -- I added the objdump greps, the system does not appear to have a tool called 'file'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The ev3dev.o file is built using:
>
> BUILD:
>          `gcc -std=c++11 -shared  ... -o ev3dev.o ev3dev.cpp`

That's your problem, right there: you've built a *shared library* and mis-named it `ev3dev.o`.

The rules for linking shared libraries is that they are *not* included into the main executable when you link against them, so no wonder `ev3dev.o` is not included into the `Touch_publisher`.

Solution: replace `-shared` with `-c` if you want `ev3dev.o` to be a normal (relocatable) object file, suitable for linking into the main executable.

Comment: Outstanding -- I figured it was something simple like a compiler flag.  I was unaware of that behavior (to not static link against a shared library).  Thank you!